# How to convert this expression from C++ to Java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a C++ expression into Java, I am not a C++ programmer, I understand that there is some left shift going on. but I don't fully understand what the OR is supposed to do. Could some one explain it or provide a equivalent expression in Java

```
     newval += ((t > val) || (std::abs(t-val) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())) << n;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
((t > val) || (std::abs(t-val) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()))
```

is a `bool` in C++, which is implicitly converted to an unsigned integer, namely `0` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`).  You are correct that the `<<` operator is a left-shift by n.

If you can perform the same logical tests in Java, you should create an integer with value 0 or 1, depending on the outcome of the tests, and bitshift that.

The `epsilon` function is a [well documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) part of the C++ standard library; you will have to use [an equivalent function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in Java.

Comment: It might not be immediately obvious which function in the java.lang.Math package is "equivalent" to std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon().  Actually there is no function that _returns_ machine epsilon, but you can calculate it like this:  `Math.nextAfter(1.0f, 2.0f) - 1.0f`

Comment: Oops!  I missed that.  I've never used Java for scientific computing.

Comment: I guess it should be Math.ulp(1.0f) for float? I don't know why people following C++ tag were so annoyed and downvoted this question

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things about the bool part of the expression (see @NicholasM's answer) that puzzle me:

(1) Use of absolute value.  The right hand side of the shortcut or operator (||) will never be evaluated if t>val.  Therefore the bool part of the expression is equivalent to this:

```
((t > val) || ((t-val) > std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()))
```

(2) When you write it that way, then it becomes obvious that the right hand side of the shortcut or can never be true if the left hand side is not true.  So, in fact the bool part reduces to `t > val` and the whole expression reduces to:

```
newval += (t > val) << n;
```

I would code that in Java like this:

```
newval += (t > val) ? 1<<n : 0;
```

Actually, I would code it like that in C++ too because it makes my intent more obvious to the reader.  A good compiler should emit the same machine language instructions in either case.

(3) I read the bool part of the expression as "t is greater than val, or t is *significantly* greater than val" where "significantly" is defined as the absolute difference being greater than machine epsilon.  I'm not even going to ask about the amazing coincidence:  i.e., why machine epsilon happens to be just the right order of magnitude to signify "significance" for your particular data.

(4) Why are you calculating with floats?  The `float` data type (IEEE 32-bit binary format) is useful for *storing* numbers when space-efficient storage is a high priority, but it's almost always better to calculate with `double` (IEEE 64-bit binary).

Comment: That's a good point about the tests.  One case, however, in which the second part of the `or` condition is relevant is exact float equality.  If `t == val`, then `(t-val) == 0.0` and the second test is true.  Another things to consider is that for values less than 1.0, i.e. have smaller float exponent, it is possible that `t < val`, AND the difference between the two is less than `epsilon()`, which is equal to ULP at 1.0.